# Can I get visa on arrival for Dubai?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, passports, tourist-visas, dubai

I am an Indian citizen. I have a B1/B2 US visa, (got it last year) but I have never travelled to the US yet. Can I use that visa to get a Visa on arrival in Dubai? Has anybody done such a thing before? Or is it a good idea to get a Visa beforehand? Has anyone been refused a visa in such a case? I have already booked Emirates flight from India.

Answer (score 2):

[From the UAE government](https://government.ae/en/information-and-services/visa-and-emirates-id/do-you-need-an-entry-permit-or-a-visa-to-enter-the-uae/visa-on-arrival):

> Indian citizens holding a normal passport and either
>
> - a visit visa issued by the USA or
> - a green card issued by the USA or
> - a residence visa issued by the UK or
> - a residence visa issued by the EU
>
> can obtain a visa on arrival for a maximum stay of 14 days provided that the visas or the green card is valid for at least six months from the date of arrival into the UAE.

There is no requirement that you’ve used your US visa in order to be eligible, as long as the visa is still valid for at least 6 months.